# MongoJack in Java gets an exception calling the method getSavedObjects

Tags: java, mongodb, jackson

I'm having an issue with mapping a Java POJO to my MongoDb records using MongoJack. It seems that I can insert the objects to the DB using the mapping but when I use the getSavedObjects method the following exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at org.mongojack.internal.util.JacksonAccessor.invoke(JacksonAccessor.java:153)
at org.mongojack.internal.util.JacksonAccessor.findDeserializer(JacksonAccessor.java:44)
at org.mongojack.internal.util.IdHandlerFactory.getIdHandlerForProperty(IdHandlerFactory.java:40)
at org.mongojack.JacksonDBCollection.<init>(JacksonDBCollection.java:137)
at org.mongojack.JacksonDBCollection.wrap(JacksonDBCollection.java:181)
at com.mytest.testdb.tests.integration.persistence.PersistenceIntegrationTests.test_shouldInsertTestObject(PersistenceIntegrationTests.java:27)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.mongojack.internal.util.JacksonAccessor.invoke(JacksonAccessor.java:149)
... 10 more
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Argument #0 of constructor [constructor for com.mytest.testdb.tests.integration.persistence.PersistenceIntegrationTests$TestObject, annotations: {interface com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator=@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator()}] has no property name annotation; must have name when multiple-paramater constructor annotated as Creator
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:272)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:247)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:146)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findRootValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:322)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._findRootDeserializer(ObjectMapper.java:2990)
... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument #0 of constructor [constructor for com.mytest.testdb.tests.integration.persistence.PersistenceIntegrationTests$TestObject, annotations: {interface com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator=@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator()}] has no property name annotation; must have name when multiple-paramater constructor annotated as Creator
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory.findValueInstantiator(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:283)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.buildBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:263)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.createBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:168)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer2(DeserializerCache.java:405)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:354)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:267)
... 17 more
```

This is the Class I have created...

```
public class TestObject{
    private String id;
    private String myString;

    public TestObject(String myString) {
        this.myString = myString;
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public TestObject(@JsonProperty("_id")String id, @JsonProperty("my_string") String myString) {
        this.id = id;
        this.myString = myString;
    }

    @ObjectId
    @JsonProperty("_id")
    String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @ObjectId
    @JsonProperty("_id")
    void setId(String id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    @JsonProperty("my_string")
    String getMyString() {
        return myString;
    }

    @JsonProperty("my_string")
    void setMyString(String myString) {
        this.myString = myString;
    }
}
```

... and this is the code I use to persist it and read the result

```
@Test
public void PersistenceIntegrationTests.test_shouldInsertTestObject(){
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
    DB db = mongoClient.getDB("TestDb");
    TestObject testObject = new TestObject(1,"My String 1");
    DBCollection dbCollection = db.getCollection("TestObjects");
    JacksonDBCollection<TestObject, String> collection = 
        JacksonDBCollection.wrap(dbCollection, TestObject.class, String.class);

    WriteResult<TestObject,String> result = collection.insert(testObject);

    List<TestObject> savedObjects = result.getSavedObjects();
}
```

I'm sure it has something to with the JsonCreator annotation but I can't seem to figure out how, I have been following the [tutorial](http://mongojack.org/tutorial.html) on the MongoJack site, but when you copy that code it doesn't even compile. How do I get the objects to serialise the results  correctly when it inserts to the database and I call the getSavedObjects?

Note: I can verify the records are actually successfully written to the DB.

Comment: Can you try and remove the `@JsonProperty` annotations from your getters and setters? They are of no use since you have annotated the constructor.

Comment: I have removed the @JsonProperty from the getters and setters and am still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you check the import statements for Jackson annotations? For instance, that all imports are com.fasterxml.jackson.* and that there are no org.codehaus.jackson.*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that if your pojo class is an inner class, although you will be able to write records to the db you will have a bad time trying to serialize it back from mongo into the pojo using mongojack. Once I had extracted TestObject from the same file as my Test everything worked.

**Note:** When I'm playing around with new concepts or frameworks in an application I'm developing I test them from a unit test and I'll often write my classes as inner classes within the test just so that it's all there in front of me while I'm playing around. If I want to use any of this experiment code I then extract the classes if they end up being useful or remove the test if it has no further relevance to what I'm doing.